# Plots not showing in ggplot2 with geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, kaggle

I am trying to plot stacked bars using `ggplot()` and `geom_bar()`

Sample data (Titanic Kaggle question):

```
PassengerId   Survived   Age
          1          0    25
          2          1    20
          3          1    40
          4          0    10
```

I am trying to show stacked bars of survival and death for each age range (I have divided age into bins). Plot is not visible when I execute the command. and when I add print() function, I get the error as

> Error: No layers in plot

Please tell if there is anything I am missing out here ?

```
breaks <- seq(min(train$Age), max(train$Age), 10)
p <- ggplot(train, aes(x=train$Age, y=length(train$PassengerId)), xlab = "age", ylab = "count", main = "survival", 
   fill = Survived + geom_bar(stat = "identity", bin = breaks))

print(p)
```

"train" is object in which I stored the data.

Comment: In `ggplot(train, aes(x=train$Age, y=length(train$PassengerId))`, `y` is of length 1. Maybe you need `seq_length(PassengerId)`.

Comment: @Pascal I tried that, same error.

Comment: Yes, you need `p <- ggplot(train, aes(x=Age, y=length(PassengerId)), xlab = "age", ylab = "count", main = "survival", 
   fill = Survived) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", bin = breaks)`. i.e. put `geom_bar` out of `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apart from Pascal's hint, you may want to:

- Use factors for colored column (Survived)
- Use different geom_bar() and aes() params as suggested

Code:

```
train <- data.frame(PassengerId = 1:4, Survived = factor(c(0,1,1,0)), Age = c(25, 20, 40, 10))
BIN.WIDTH <- 10
my.breaks <- seq(from = min(train$Age), to = max(train$Age) + BIN.WIDTH, by = BIN.WIDTH)
ggplot(train, aes(Age, fill = Survived)) + geom_bar(breaks = my.breaks)
```

Plot:

[image: Stacked chart produced]

Comment: I used `ggplot(train, aes(Age, fill = Survived), xlab = "age", ylab = "count", main = "Survival") + 
     geom_bar(breaks = breaks)` and getting error: `Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`

Comment: What does the variable `train` look like? (e.g. show us result of `str(train)`)

Comment: Also what ggplot library do you use? I use library(ggplot2)

Comment: it got resolved. It was showing that error beacuse Survived was not stored as factor in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

First you should remove the rows where age is NA, otherwise you can't create a sequence.

```
train<-train[!is.na(train$Age),]
```

Then you should change your y value to `train$Survived` (why did you use `length(train$PassengerId)`? - it doesn't display anything)
The thing that @Pascal mentioned is also correct: You have to put `+ geom_bar(stat="identity", bin=breaks)` outside.
and you need to add the axes and title differently in ggplot.

This is the complete working code:

```
train<-train[!is.na(train$Age),]

breaks <- seq(min(train$Age), max(train$Age), 10)
p <- ggplot(train, aes(x=train$Age, y=train$Survived), 
            fill = Survived)+ geom_bar(stat="identity", bin=breaks)
p <- p+labs(x="age", y="count")

p <- p+theme(plot.title= element_text("survival"))


print(p)
```

Results in this graph:
[image]